# wordpress https effects.js issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I added SSL to a domain running Wordpress. When I access through https I get

Reference error: $ is not defined in resources/effects.js and the functions using this script break.

If I access through http then no error.

I did a Google search but could not find any reference to an issue like this. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you loading jquery in your pages with http://?

Comment: nope <script src='//cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js'></script>.

Comment: What happend if you try loading jquery and jquery tools as two seperate libs

Comment: i could not find a seperate lib for version 1.2.7. i tried: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> but the scripts on the page do not work with this.

Comment: have you tried using 'jQuery' instead of the '$'

Comment: the script is fine, it works through http. the issue is when calling through https i get the above error. i cannot think of any logical reason why changing $ to jQuery will help. but as i am completely clueless as to why this is happening, i will try that later today :)

Comment: jquery has a no conflict mode, Im sure that wordpress uses 'jQuery' rather then the '$' symbol.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and solution. Turns out the particular jquery library i was calling was not available from the cdn over a https connection. It took a while to figure out because i was using the Firefox console to debug and it showed a successful connection, 200 OK. I eventually switched to Chrome js console and it showed this error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE.

Also Google does not host the 1.2.7 library and the only cdn i could find that has it is cloudflare:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tools/1.2.7/jquery.tools.min.js